# SQL - Convert Many-Many Bridge Table to One-One Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am struggling at writing a query to get data from a table like this:

```
id    food_id    ingre_id
1     1          13
2     1          9
3     2          13
4     3          5
5     4          9
6     4          10
7     5          5
```

Assume in that table, each `food` only have 1 or 2 ingre ids. Then I want to have a table like this:

```
item_id    ingre1_id    ingre2_id
1          13           9
2          13           null //any food that have 1 ingre then set ingre2_id to null
3          5            null
4          9            10
5          5            null
```

Please suggest me a query to do such conversion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  If you don't care about the ordering within a row:

```
select food_id, min(ingred_id) as ingred1_id,
       (case when min(ingred_id) <> max(ingred_id) then max(ingred_id) end) as ingred2_id
from t
group by food_id;
```

Note:  This use of `min()`/`max()` works specifically because you have two values.  If you have more values, then ask *another* question with appropriate data.

Comment: @SloanThrasher . . . Do you know what `case` does?  This quite intentionally does *not* do that.

Answer (score 0):

This should produce what you asked for:

```
SELECT
    a.`food_id` as `item_id`,
    a.`ingre_id` as `ingre1_id`,
    b.`ingre_id` as `ingre2_id`
FROM `food` a
LEFT JOIN `food` b
ON a.`id` <> b.`id` AND a.`food_id` = b.`food_id`
WHERE a.`id` < b.`id` OR b.`id` IS NULL
GROUP BY a.`food_id`
```